# What is the best approach to scn directories inside condition

Tags: php

Inside a condition, I have some element in static.

```
$group == 'modules_account_customers'
```

for example

I would like to make that in dynamic (read).

How to proceed?
Below you an example of this condition.

All the directories start with `modules_`

I suppose I must use a function like a glob and select all the _modules. I don't know exactly how to start.

Any idea.

Tk.

```
 foreach ( $modules_array as $module ) {
              $class = basename($module, '.php');

// module language
              if ( !class_exists($class) ) {
               if ( MODE_VENTE_PRIVEE == 'true' && $customer->isLoggedOn() ) {
                  $modules_boxes = 'modules_boxes';
               } elseif (MODE_VENTE_PRIVEE == 'true' && !$customer->isLoggedOn ) {
                  $modules_boxes = '';
               } else {
                  $modules_boxes = 'modules_boxes';
               }

               if ($group == $modules_boxes ||
                   $group == 'modules_account_customers' ||
                   $group == 'modules_account_history_info' ||
                   $group == 'modules_advanced_search' ||
                   $group == 'modules_blog' ||
                   $group == 'modules_blog_content' ||
                   $group == 'modules_create_account' ||
                ) { .....}
             }
   }
```

I started by this and allow to display the directories inside an array :

```
    public function getReadModulesDefaultDirectories($source_folder = 'modules_') {
  $dir = $this->_directoryTemplateSources . '/' . $this->_template . '/' . $this->_codeSail . '/' . $this->_directoryModules;

  $module_directories = array_diff(glob($dir . $source_folder . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR), $exclude);

  $result = [];

  foreach ($module_directories as $value) {
    $result[] = str_replace($dir, '', $value);
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Comment: What does "I would to make that in dynamic with element could be exluded" mean?

Comment: @Alberto I create a function can scan the directories, now the problem is o read this to insert inside the condition $group == $this->getReadModulesDefaultDirectories(), but the function return an array, not a string like modules_account_customers